# Bridge shield between Arduino and Raspberry Pi (to wirelessly upload the measurements of analog sensors to a webpage)?

Tags: arduino, raspberry-pi

I like to build a project to make my gardening work smarter! My goal is to measure soil temperature, soil water content, light intensity and also taking a picture, and then wirelessly upload these datasets to a webpage. I can also control the irrigation system (turn on/off the pump switch) via the webpage.

These sensors are anagogic! However, the Raspberry Pi Face (PiFace) Digital Interface is only able to take care of digital signals. The PiFace comes with the relaies, which is pretty handy for a startup project. I just like to get some premade boards and ensemble them easily without too work.

1. Can I layer up a Raspberry Pi board, an Arduino bridge shield, an Arduino board and a PiFace (or a relay board) without wiring?
2. I really need a recommended "shopping list" to start with. What should I choose?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you try following the steps outlined in *[Arduino and the Raspberry Pi](http://www.deanmao.com/2012/08/06/arduino-and-the-raspberry-pi/)*.

Answer (score 0):

I agree that you should involve an Arduino as your conduit to the outside world. Then do a simple serial connection between the two. If you get any Arduino except for the new Due, you have got to get from 5 V (Arduino) to 3.3 V (Raspberry Pi). I'd suggest [Sparkfun's Logic Level converter](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/8745).

Sparkfun also has a good light sensor, *[TEMT6000 Breakout Board](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/8688)*.

While you're there, you can grab a couple of thermistors to measure temperature, *[Thermistor 10K](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/250)*.

Also, [Make](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Make_%28magazine%29) did an article on almost exactly what you intend on doing (from the Arduino side), *[Microcontroller-assisted gardening](http://www.make-digital.com/make/vol18/?pg=94#pg94)*.

On the Raspberry Pi side, [Pygame](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pygame) will give you a huge head-start on connecting to the Arduino and taking webcam shots. *[A Halloween Sound Trigger with Raspberry Pi and Arduino](http://blog.makezine.com/2012/10/22/a-halloween-sound-trigger-with-raspberry-pi-and-arduino/)* should get you started.

Answer (score 0):

According to what you describe, you may achieve this with only an Arduino UNO, an Ethernet Shield, sensors (at least temperature and light) and a cheap CMOS camera.

If you want to take advantage of the two worlds (Raspberry with  Arduino I/O capabilities), you may also consider the [Raspberry Pi to Arduino shields connection bridge](http://www.cooking-hacks.com/index.php/raspberry-pi-to-arduino-shield-connection-bridge.html) from [Cooking-Hacks](http://www.cooking-hacks.com/): they provide both [library](http://www.cooking-hacks.com/index.php/documentation/tutorials/raspberry-pi-to-arduino-shields-connection-bridge#step4) and [tutorial](http://www.cooking-hacks.com/index.php/documentation/tutorials/raspberry-pi-to-arduino-shields-connection-bridge) to start with.